# how do count down every time on same view with react native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am new to react and react native.  I am using the expo cli to build a react native app.  How do I restart a countdown every time view is viewed by a user?  unmount doesn't work since this never unmount.
What I want is to count down to 15 to 0 and then show the continue button but this only works once.

```
function ContinueStatus({ onContinuePress }) {
      let [count, setTimer] = useState(15);
  let [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer(lastTimerCount => {
          lastTimerCount <= 1 && clearInterval(interval);
          count = lastTimerCount;
          return lastTimerCount - 1
      })
    }, 1000) 
    //cleanup the interval on complete
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [isStarted]);

    return( 
      count > 0 ?
        (<Button color="primary" style={styles.createButton}>
        <Text bold size={14} color={myTheme.COLORS.WHITE}>
          Continue in {count} second(s)
        </Text>
        </Button> )
      :
       (<Button color="primary" style={styles.createButton} onPress={onContinuePress} >
            <Text bold size={14} color={myTheme.COLORS.WHITE}>
              Continue
            </Text>
          </Button> 
       )
  ) 
}
render() { 
    return (
          <ContinueStatus onContinuePress={this.onContinuePress}/> 
  );
}
```

Comment: So every time a user goes to the screen, the countdown restarts?

Comment: yes, that's what I want

Answer (score 1):

The problem is is that your component doesn't unmount when you navigate away from it. This is one significant difference between ReactJS and React Native. The problem can be solved by using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) and the `useFocusEffect` hook.

> The useFocusEffect is analogous to React's useEffect hook. The only difference is that it only runs if the screen is currently focused.

So replace `useEffect` with `useFocusEffect` and make sure to use `useCallback` like it describes [in the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/).

You may also need to set up the router with a provider, but try it without first.

Comment: thanks for that, I tried the useFocusEffect but didn't work.  I guess I have to set up the router...  I hoping not to do that

Comment: How are you navigating to and from the screen?

Comment: using one of those mobile templates and it's using Stack.Navigator

Comment: Ok, well you also need to clean up your code - change all your `lets` for `consts`. These variables should be immutable. Then, why do you need this line? `count = lastTimerCount;`

Comment: yea, I was testing but that still wont' fix my issue thou

Comment: what's a good navigation and route practice for react-native?

Comment: Sorry that's a different question to the original one